# Is there a map or list in java that allows associating two objects with eachother?

Tags: java

I would need a list/map like a HashMap where i can easily access either 'side' by simple passing the object and retrieving the other thing.

I need to be able to use get(key) and retrieve the value as well as get(value) and retrieve the key AND i want to be able to set a new key or value.

Is there already something like that ?

Comment: Guava's BiMap, i think

Comment: Use two HashMaps, one for each direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two popular choices are

- Guava's [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)
- Apache Commons [BidiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BidiMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in data type for this. You can use Guava's `BiMap` and do this with `reverse()` function. See [this](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).